# вывод ресурсов определенного пользователя Modx revo

Tags: php, cms, modx, revo

Подскажите , сделал через фронтенд добавление ресурсов с помощью плагина Login

есть дерево категорий:

Категории(2)
 -авто(3)
 -дети(4)
 -новый год(5)

Как мне сделать вывод всех ресурсов добавленных определенным пользователем из всех подкатегорий

пробовал вот так, но выдает названия подкатегорий

```
[[!getResources? 
    &parents=`2` 
    &limit=`1` 
    &tpl=`myads` 
    &depth=`10` 
    &showHidden=`1` 
    &includeTVs=`1` 
    &processTVs=`1` 
    &where=`{*createdby:is=`[[!+modx.user.id]]`} `
]]
```

вот чанк myads

```
<p>[[+pagetitle]]</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

В параметре `where` ты сделал всё совершенно неправильно. Там указывается валидная конструкция [modx where](https://docs.modx.com/xpdo/2.x/class-reference/xpdoquery/xpdoquery.where) преобразованная в Json Объект. Должно это выглядеть так:

```
[[!getResources? 
    &parents=`2`  
    &limit=`1`  
    &tpl=`myads`  
    &depth=`10`  
    &showHidden=`1`  
    &includeTVs=`1`  
    &processTVs=`1`  
    &where=`{"createdby:=":[[!+modx.user.id]]}` 
]]
```